# How to transform a HTTP POST to an email?

Tags: email, http-post

I use a mail service which can send HTTP POST requests to a URL with information about failed messages.  What I would really like is to get an email about any failed messages.

Are there websites (URLs) that can accept HTTP POST requests and translate them into emails?  Or other reasonable easy to implement solutions to convert the mail service's HTTP POSTs into email notifications?

[This is just for my own personal 1-user use; so I don't need a solution that scales well or is able to process vast numbers of HTTP POST requests or anything of that sort.]

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to use PHP to read the POST with

> $_POST["yourPostedStuffHere"];

and send the data via mail with

> mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);

See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

It's not very beautiful, but for personal use it would work.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the web / integration service Zapier can accept incoming webhooks to trigger emails i believe.

They offer services to interconnect several different apps, including sending/receiving webhooks, as well as emails.